# How to get data from User related model to template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have Profile model in addition to native User model.
Since user is logged in, I need to load avatar image to all pages in frontend.
I need something like this:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}<img src={{ profile.avatar }}>{% endif %}
```

How I can do that?

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/avatar/', verbose_name='Аватар',
                           default='media/avatar/default_avatar.jpg')

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the `related_name` of `user` field:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/avatar/', verbose_name='Аватар', default='media/avatar/default_avatar.jpg')
```

Then you can write:

```html
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}<img src={{ request.user.profile.avatar }}>{% endif %}
```

To display the avatar in all templates, you can define a base template from which all others inherit, look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/) for details.